# Gnuplot script combine "embedded" format with indexed blocks

Tags: gnuplot

Basically, I want to combine http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html#7.4 and http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html#7.2. I'm trying to get a gnuplot script with embedded plaintext data points to plot using three different colours all in one plot command, like so:

```
plot \
    "-" index 0 title "waveform" with lines, \
    "-" index 1 title "-trig"    with lines, \
    "-" index 2 title "+trig"    with lines
    1418    -0.04
    1419    -0.04
    1420    +5.28
    1421    +5.20
    1422    +5.16

    1418    3.66
    1422    3.66

    1418    3.86
    1422    3.86
end
```

However, it just displays the three blocks in one colour and throws an error on the second and third index commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I finally guessed it into working:

```
plot \
    "-" title ""      with lines, \
    "-" title "-trig" with lines, \
    "-" title "+trig" with lines
    1418    -0.04
    1419    -0.04
    1420    +5.28
    1421    +5.20
    1422    +5.16
end
    1418    3.66
    1422    3.66
end
    1418    3.86
    1422    3.86
end
```